# перестал работать скрол

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#article-nav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
            return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length-1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("isActive")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("isActive");
   } 
});
```

ошибку показывает в этой строке  `offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;`

с алиасом перестал работать скрол,

```
<a href="тут-какой-то-алиас#ссылка на элемент">
```

вот так работало без проблем

```
<a href="#ссылка-на-элемент">
```

Comment: потому что `$("#....")` это валидный селектор, а `$('бла бла бла #....')` нет. разделите ваш href на две части до # и после. Если до не совпадает с текущим url страницы, то вообще обрабатывать не надо. В противном случае используйте полученный якорь

Comment: а по подробней можно ?

Comment: как мне его разделить ? регулярками ?

Comment: а вы видите какую то регулярность в примере `asd#zxc` ? Тут  один четкий разделитель. К чему тут регулярки?

Comment: хорошо, тогда как мне правильно разделить ?

Comment: если у вас в меню все ссылки на текущую страницу, то можете брать просто `$(this).hash` при клике на ссылку.

Comment: я попробовал так ' var href = $(this).hash("href")' не сработало

Answer (score 1):

ищите якорь в `this.hash`

```js
$("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   
   console.log(this.hash);

   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#hash">with hash</a>
<a href="/no-hash">w/o hash</a>
```

то есть в вашем случае

```
 offsetTop = this.hash === '' ? 0 : $(this.hash).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
```

Comment: я думаю мне просто нужно вот в этой строчке
offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
указать что-то типа
offsetTop = href  == " " == "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
но так не работает

Comment: @evsykov дополнил

Comment: к сожалению не сработало, ошибка в этой строке

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5 всё не буду копировать, так как ссылка русская

Comment: @evsykov из контекста вашего вопроса следовало, что все якори в ссылках меню были привязаны к элементам на странице. Если якорь это русский текст, то очевидно валидным слекетором он быть не может. разберитесь с тем, какие данные у вас в наличии